# How to import contract source code in etherscan.io

Tags: parity, etherscan, parity-wallet

I'd like to learn which solidity source code is being used when I create a multisign Wallet in Parity 1.6

My goal is to import that source code into
https://kovan.etherscan.io/verifyContract?a=0xFe9b44592d4E15e9e43605d87C13958A2da42501

So I can browse the methods easily.
here is what I tried: 
https://github.com/paritytech/parity/blob/master/js/src/contracts/snippets/wallet.sol
to paste this source code, but I get the following error:

> Sorry! The Compiled Contract ByteCode for 'multisig' does NOT match the 
>     Contract Creation Code for [0xFe9b44592d4E15e9e43605d87C13958A2da42501].

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct source code? It looks like that contract is deployed by another contract. Have you deployed both?

Comment: @jeff, I created a wallet which is by design is a contract and I also created another wallet which is also by design a contract and creator of the wallet was the first wallet. But it should not matter, what matter is how do you create a wallet in Parity and convert bytecode to source code in etherscan after you created it. If you could try it yourself and provide any feedback - I'd be really appreciated!

Comment: You cannot convert the bytecode to source code. You can try disassemblers but it will not be the same. That's why I asked. If you already have the source code (that you computed the bytecode from), you should save it somewhere and verify with that.

Comment: So, how should I use etherscan.io feature to Verify and Publish your Solidity Source Code  for published contract?

Comment: How do you call the execute() function? It passes whatever is supplied as `_data`. Maybe it is not the full source code compiled but something else.

Comment: that's why I was asking if you create a multi-sig wallet in parity client, how can I learn the source code behind it, so I can paste it in the etherscan. Have you tried creating one?

Comment: I'm using [this one](https://github.com/ethereum/dapp-bin/blob/master/wallet/wallet.sol).

Comment: The title of this question doesn't match the body (but I upvoted anyway because the body is interesting and clear.) It might help to post the steps you used to create the wallet.